# Output of BufferedReader is changing the bits

Tags: java, android, sockets

So my app connects an Android to another device and sends/receives serial data over wifi. It is able to connect, disconnect, and transmit data flawlessly, however, when data is received, this happens...

I know for a fact that the transmitting device works and is not sending this incorrect data.

Does anyone have any clue why this would be happening or how to prevent it?

The only byte that I can determine causes this is 0x05.

Incoming Bits: 11111111 11111101
Incoming Bits: 00000000 00001100
Incoming Bits: 11111111 11111101
Incoming Bits: 00000000 00111101
Incoming Bits: 11111111 11111101
Incoming Bits: 00000001 00010011
Incoming Bits: 00000000 00111101
Incoming Bits: 11111111 11111101

```
    private void asyncRead()
    {
        BufferedReader tIn = null;
        try
        {
            tIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        while (true)
        {
            char[] tBuffer = new char[500];
            int tNumberOfChars = 0;

            try
            {
                tNumberOfChars = tIn.read(tBuffer);
            } catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (tNumberOfChars <= 0) continue;

            byte[] tBytes = new byte[tNumberOfChars];

            for (int i = 0; i < tBytes.length; ++i)
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "Incoming Bits: " + Utilities.bitStringFromChar(tBuffer[i]));
            }

            publishProgress(tBytes);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What happens? What is your expected output and what the actual?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `byte[]` buffer and a `BufferedInputStream` if you expect bitwise identity. `BufferedReader` is for use when you know the data is text and you want it transformed into UTF-16. In this case, you don't.

NB:

1. Code that depends on the success of code in a `try` block should be inside that `try` block.
2. You allocate `tBytes` and then put nothing into it. I can't imagine why.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! Using `BufferedInputStream` solved the problem! Also a good suggestion for the `try` block. I had omitted the specific code for populating `tBytes`.